# Quarkus 2.5: @Inject inside JAX-RS Application subclass not working anymore

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, quarkus

After upgrading Quarkus from 1.6.1.Final to 2.5.Final the following `@Inject` fails inside `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` subclass:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBean {

    public String foo() {
        retun "bar";
    }
}
```

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Inject
    MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        myBean.foo(); // Causes NPE on Quarkus 2.5.Final, worked well with 1.6.1.Final
    
    }
}
```

I tried with `CDI.current().select(MyBean.class).get()` but got `Unable to locate CDIProvider`.

Any other workaround I can try? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect a couple of things: (1) `CDI.current().select(...)` should not work because Quarkus is using ARC instead of real CDI and ARC is doing its "magic" at build time, not runtime (2) You may need to add a scope to the `Application`, so that ARC "sees" it as a bean and does injection. I may be widely wrong here :) just a few things out of my head in case they help!

Comment: I think this is an inherent limitation we have with `Application`...

Comment: For the record, even though ArC doesn't pass the CDI TCK, it does implement a rather big part of CDI, including `CDI.current()`. If that doesn't work, there's probably something wrong and I'd suggest filling a bug with a minimal reproducer.

Comment: @Ladicek, @NikosParaskevopoulos: the code above works fine on 1.6.1.Final (I can also do `CDI.current() ...`). Digging a bit more into it, it looks like application initialization procedure changed with Quarkus 2.5 (2.0?). JAX RS Application now gets initialized before ARC takes care of the CDI beans. Hence `myBean` is null inside `getClasses()` method ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Inject` in JAX-RS Application classes has been since [disallowed](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/22440). I was able to solve my issue (registering resource classes by config) using `@IfBuildProperty` annotation.